# Django query to get sum of previous values

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset, window-functions

I have the following table of logs that stores operations. An override operation means an absolute value stored, while add and sub operations are variance values. The override operations are like checkpoints.

```
Id    operation       quantity   
---------------------------------------------------------
1     ADD             10.00 
2     ADD             20.00 
3     OVERRIDE        15.00 
4     SUB            -5.00   
5     SUB            -10.00
```

My goal is to get the following results with one query

```
Id    operation       quantity       calculated_total_quantity
---------------------------------------------------------
1     ADD             10.00          10.00
2     ADD             20.00          30.00
3     OVERRIDE        15.00          15.00
4     SUB            -5.00           10.00
5     SUB            -10.00          0.00
```

I tried the following query

```
Logs.objects.all().annotate(
   calculated_total_quantity=Case(
        When(operation="OVERRIDE", then=F('quantity')),
        default=Window(
            expression=Sum(F('quantity')),
            order_by=F('id').asc()
        )
    )
)
```

With this query I am getting wrong results:

```
Id    operation       quantity       calculated_total_quantity
---------------------------------------------------------
1     ADD             10.00          10.00
2     ADD             20.00          30.00
3     OVERRIDE        15.00          15.00
4     SUB            -5.00           40.00
5     SUB            -10.00          30.00
```

I know that the error is because of the Sum expression, so my questions is if there is any way to reset the Sum expression to start again when the log operations is OVERRIDE.

If anyone can help me with this I will be more than grateful.

Comment: Avoid complicated database queries in django. Write a database view instead, it will just simplify django ORM, and of course make your life easier :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Case in this query...
simply write

```
Logs.objects.all().annotate(
   calculated_total_quantity=Window(
            expression=Sum(F('quantity')),
            order_by=F('id').asc()
        )
    )
```